# Re-entry into Israel as tourist (Australian citizen)

Tags: visas, israel, australian-citizens

I am Australian and I plan to visit Israel on a tourist visa for three months from end of May to end of August. I will be travelling out of Israel to Copenhagen third week of August for six days and am wondering if the 90-day admission period will be "reset" - meaning a new period of 90 days from the date of entry - once I return to Israel from Copenhagen???

If not, how can I extend my stay in Israel? I've read that I can apply for an extension at the population registration office?

Answer (score 1):

The relevant agency is the Interior Ministry (Misrad ha-Panim), arrive early, and expect to wait most of the day. Fifteen years ago, the clock reset under the circumstances you give, but the rule may have changed since I used it.